# Can I Colab combo disable

Tags: google-colaboratory, disable

[Colab combo message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K6c8V.png)

When I use colab i can see a combo message.
Can i disable combo message?
I just change Hardware acceleration None to GPU.

Answer (score 11):

https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/803

If you go to Tools -> Preferences -> Miscellaneous, you can disable both of these there:

set "Power level" to "No power"

Comment: it's moved to Tools > Settings > Miscellaneous > Power Level > No Power